# onmouse over with an anchor on watir, not detecting

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, watir

I am trying to trigger a mouse over drop down window in Watir on ruby.

I have tried it using both of the two scripts below, so far neither have worked.:

```
$browser.div(:class => "rolloverMAINMenu").fire_event("onMouseOver")
```

and

```
$browser.a(:style=>"background-color:cccccc;width:200px;").fire_event("onMouseOver")
```

HTML:

```
<font COLOR="green">
<a style="background-color:cccccc;width:200px;" onmouseover="rolloverMenu(1, 'mainMenu');" onmouseout="rolloverMenu(0, 'mainMenu');"
onclick="rolloverMenu(0, 'mainMenu');">
&nbsp;&nbsp;<B> Roll Over Menu </B></a>

 <div style="background-color:cccccc;width:200px;" class="rolloverMAINMenu"   id="mainMenu"    style="display: none;" onmouseover="rolloverMenu(1, 'mainMenu');"`
```

Comment: What happens when you execute the code you tried?   Have you tried .flash with both of those to be sure you are getting the right object? (since there could be other objects with the same class or style)  Have you tried all lower case for the event name (as it appears in the HTML) instead of camelCase?

Comment: The first line compiles and doesn't visible do anything, the second results in the error:
`assert_exists': Unable to locate element, using :style, "background-color:cccccc;width:200px;" (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

I am struggling on simply detecting it at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the div, since it has an ID, I'd recommend using that to identify it since ID values should (according to the HTML spec) should be unique on the page.  That will insure you are selecting the correct element.

Secondly since the code is looking for 'onmouseover'  I would specify the event that way and not use camelCase

```
browser.div(:id, 'mainMenu').fire_event('onmouseover')
```

For the link, the problem you are having is identifying it.  I do not see :style listed as an option for [identifying elements](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir) (although potentially that doc could be out of date) I might suggest using the text or some other aspect, or you may need to resort to xpath.

```
browser.link(:text, /Roll Over Menu/).fire_event('onmouseover')
```

Or since the link is set to react to click, you could try that also

```
browser.link(:text, /Roll Over Menu/).click
```

If you are placing these in a script, since the client is executing javascript methods in response to the events, you may need to have a small pause in the script at that point to allow for the DOM to be updated, before you try to interact with any elements rendered to the screen in response to the mouseover or click